# Error in Rolling back the tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

When I run `php artisan migrate:refresh` in the terminal, I get the following error. Why am I getting this error?

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'departments' already exists (SQL: create table `departments` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(191) not null, `deleted_at` timestamp null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci engine = InnoDB)
>
> [PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'departments' already exists

Comment: Okay2 @KenWhite

Comment: I updated already @KenWhite

Comment: I edited already @KenWhite

Comment: did you write `down` function for departments yet?

Comment: Much better. Thanks (from me and all of the mobile users here).

Comment: Yes sir @HoàngĐăng

Comment: Can you remove the down vote? Thanks @KenWhite

Comment: I added the downvote, because you didn't include relevant information in your question.

Comment: I never downvoted, so I can't remove it. I just left a comment, which I deleted after your edit because the comment no longer applied.

Comment: With regard to your question, you usually get that error when your migrations are out of sync. The database has been rolled back, and when recreating the table `departments`, it's found to already exist. If you're dropping all tables anyway, it would be easiest to manually drop all tables, and to re-run your migrations. Then run `php artisan migrate:refresh` again to see if anything in your migrations is actually still broken.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `php artisan migrate:fresh` it should help. But the problem is some `down` method in the migrate does not cancel `up` method changes or you have changed some migrations after ran `php artisan migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if you have the **down()** method configured in your *departments* migration.

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('departments');
}
```